# TryParse a String and Then Testing It's Value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox where I want people to type an integer (not a double) that is not 0 and less than 5. The variable `numofitems` stores the value of the textbox, and when you press a button, it will convert it to an int and test if it fits the requirements I want. This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string numofitems = textBox1.Text;

    int x = 0;

    if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && numofitems !=0 && numofitems <=5)
    {

        //it is valid
    }
}
```

Although, it says:

> operator != cannot be applied to operands of 'string' and 'int'.

How can I fix this? I don't want to test it's value first because then people can enter `00` into the text box and it will work. Thanks!

Comment: Replace `numofitems` in the second two conditions with `x`. `TryParse` won't change `nomofitems` to an int, it will take the integer value and output it as `x`.

Comment: you are comparing string with integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing with the wrong variable. The converted resulting `int` value will be in `x`! so you would need to check with `x`. `numofitems` remains unchanged (especially the type) when you try to convert the string into a number.

The solution would look like this:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && x !=0 && x <=5)
{

    //it is valid
}
```

ps. If you mean the number of items should be between 0 and 5 I would suggest to check like this:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && x > 0 && x <=5)
```

otherwise you allow for negative numbers!

FYI: the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following to the second parameter `out x`

> When this method returns, [the second parameter] contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s [the first/string parameter], if the conversion succeeded,

Comment: I'm new to Visual Studio; I was previously doing Unity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Does such an if clause work in unity?  Or are you not familiar with tryparse?

Comment: `tryparse` does exist in Unity, but everyone uses `int.Parse()`

Comment: Ahh, I learned something new. Yes it is very handy especially if handling user input.

Answer (score 1):

`Int32.TryParse` Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded. Your value is in `X`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string numofitems = textBox1.Text;
    int x = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && x > 0 && x <= 5)
    {
        //it is valid
    }
}
```

Read more about `Int32.TryParse` in [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your check should look like this:

```
if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && x!=0 && x<=5)
    {

        //it is valid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you declared `string numofitems` and then compare that `string` with an `int`.
Your code should be:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string numofitems = textBox1.Text;
    int x = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(numofitems, out x) && x > 0 && x <= 5)
    {
        //it is valid
    }
}
```

Note that if you want the number to be *between* 0 and 5 (positive), the first comparision should be `x > 0`.